# Database Design: Storing the primary key as a separate field in the same table

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-design, database-relations

I have a table that must reference another record, but of the same table. Here's an example:

```
Customer
********
ID
ManagerID (the ID of another customer)
...
```

I have a bad feeling about doing this. My other idea was to just have a separate table that just stored the relationship.

```
CustomerRelationship
***************
ID
CustomerID
ManagerID
```

I feel I may be over complicating such a trivial thing however, I would like to get some idea's on the best approach for this particular scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you have a "bad feeling" about this? It's perfectly acceptable for a table to reference its own primary key. Introducing a secondary table only increases the complexity of your queries and negatively impacts performance.

Comment: Wasn't quite sure what the bad feeling was. Just didn't think referencing the ID of the same table was good practise. Thanks for the reassurance tho!

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong about the first design.  The second one, where you have an 'intermediate' table, is used for many-to-many relationships, which i don't think is yours.

BTW, that intermediate table wouldn't have and ID of its own.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I was just looking for some reassurance on if the first way was ok to do.

Comment: First design is good for a simple structure where there is a one to one relationship.  If someone can have multiple reporting lines then the second option is more appropriate.

Comment: @Javier:  IMHO, you typically want to have an id field in an "intermediate" table, so that you can easily break the relationships without having to write a bunch of funky SQL to do it... it's easier to write "DELETE FROM product_suppliers where id=@id" then it is to write "DELETE FROM product_suppliers where productid=@prodid and supplierid=@suppid"

Also, if you are synchronizing the tables, I believe it is a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Can a Customer have multiple managers?  If so, then you need a separate table.
Otherwise, a single table is fine.

Comment: No customer's will only have 1 manager so I think my first solution will be fine, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the first approach. See also [Using Self-Joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177490.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with the first approach, in fact Oracle has included the 'CONNECT BY' extension to SQL since at least version 6 which is intended to directly support this type of hierarchical structure (and possibly makes Oracle worth considering as your database if you are going to be doing a lot of this).

You'll need self-joins in databases which don't have something analogous, but that's also a perfectly fine and standard solution.

Answer (score 0):

As a programmer I like the first approach. I like to have less number of tables. Here we are not even talking of normalization and why do we need more tables? That is just me.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the KISS principle here: Keep it simple, (silly | stupid | stud | [whatever epithet starting with S you prefer]). Go with one table, unless you have a reason to need more.

Note that if the one-to-many/many-to-many relationship ends up being the case, you can extract the existing column into a table of its own, and fill in the new entries at that time.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I would ever recommend avoiding such self-referecing tables is that SQL Server does have a few spots where there are limitations with self-referencing tables.

For one, if you ever happen to come across the need for an [indexed view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921.aspx), then you'd find out that if one of the tables used in a view definition is indeed self-referencing, you won't be able to create a clustered index on your view :-(

But apart from that - the design per se is sound and absolutely valid - go for it! I always like to keep things as simple as possible (but no simpler than that).

Marc